# How to disable gradle daemon in Cordova

Tags: cordova, gradle, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-daemon

How can I stop cordova from using gradle daemon?

I tried already these:

- put gradle.properties containing org.gradle.daemon=false in ~/.gradle folder doesnt work
- put gradle.properties containing org.gradle.daemon=false in project directory (same level as build.gradle) folder doesnt work

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: I decided to use script to stop gradle using ./gradlew --stop before every cordova build

Comment: Is this approach work for you? what's the difference for: gradle --no-daemon --no-build-cache

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following command to use Ant forcefully

```
cordova build android -- --ant
```

Comment: I need to use gradle in this case... The project has dependency on using gradle..   So I dont think switching to ant is a good idea..